# Can't read excel file from local directory

Tags: java, excel, struts

I have already uploaded the excel file in my local directory but the problem is that I can't read it from that location.

I am using struts 1.1 ,db2.

```
package mj.eps.action;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.servlet.ServletConfig;
import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;

import org.apache.struts.action.ActionError;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionErrors;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForm;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionForward;
import org.apache.struts.action.ActionMapping;
import com.mj.eps.dto.business.auction.UploadObject;
import com.mj.eps.dto.training.IndexValueReportObject;
import com.mj.eps.framework.util.FileScaner;
import com.mj.eps.framework.util.IConstant;

public class IndexValueAction extends EPSBaseAction{


    public IndexValueAction() {
        super();

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(
        ActionMapping mapping,
        ActionForm form,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {

        Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();
        ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
        ActionForward forward = new ActionForward(); 



        try{


            String contentType = request.getContentType();



            if ((contentType != null)
                && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {

                DataInputStream in =
                    new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());
                int formDataLength = request.getContentLength();


                byte dataBytes[] = new byte[formDataLength];
                int byteRead = 0;
                int totalBytesRead = 0;
                while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
                    byteRead =
                        in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);
                    totalBytesRead += byteRead;
                }
                String file = new String(dataBytes);

                try {

                    String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);

                    saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));                       
                    saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,   saveFile.indexOf("\""));                        
                    int lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");

                    String boundary =
                        contentType.substring(
                            lastIndex + 1,
                            contentType.length());


                    int pos;
                    pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");

                    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;

                    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;

                    pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;

                    int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;

                    int startPos = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
                    int endPos =
                        (
                            (file.substring(0, boundaryLocation))
                                .getBytes())
                                .length;

                    Vector<IndexValueReportObject> indexObjectVector = new Vector<IndexValueReportObject>();


                    Date dt = new Date();
                    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
                    df.applyPattern("dd-MM-yy hh-mm-ss");
                    saveFile =  saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("."))+ "-"+ df.format(dt)+ ".xls";

                    String uploadFilePath = ""; 
                    ServletContext sc1 = request.getSession().getServletContext();
                    Properties properties = new Properties();
                    String realPath1 = sc1.getRealPath("serverPath.properties");

                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(realPath1);
                    properties.load(fis);
                    uploadFilePath = properties.getProperty("fileUpload.path");                     
                    FileOutputStream fileOut =  new FileOutputStream(uploadFilePath + saveFile);                        
                    System.out.println(uploadFilePath); 
                    if(endPos > dataBytes.length )
                        endPos = dataBytes.length;

                    fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));

                    fileOut.flush();
                    fileOut.close();

                    Vector<String[]> rowVector = new Vector<String[]>();
                    Vector<Object> errorVector = new Vector<Object>();
                    UploadObject uploadObject = new UploadObject();
                    int errorId=0;
                    try {



                        File outFile = new File(uploadFilePath  + saveFile);            
                        ServletConfig config = getServlet();            
                        ServletContext sc = config.getServletContext();
                        boolean retVal = false;
                        boolean exists = true;              
                        String filepath = outFile.getAbsolutePath();

                        String realPath = sc.getRealPath("virusCheck.properties");

                        exists = FileScaner.loadProperty(realPath);

                        if (exists) {
                            retVal = FileScaner.checkVirus(realPath, filepath);

                            if (!retVal) {
                                FileScaner.cleanFile(filepath);                 
                                errors.add(
                                    ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR,
                                    new ActionError(
                                        "errors.dynamic",
                                        "<li>Virus found!!"));
                            }
                            if (retVal) {

                                retVal = FileScaner.checkFileSign(filepath);

                                if (!retVal) {
                                    FileScaner.cleanFile(filepath);                 
                                    errors.add(
                                        ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR,
                                        new ActionError(
                                            "errors.dynamic",
                                            "<li>File type not supported!!"));
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                        }
                        if (retVal) {
                        }
                        if (errors.isEmpty())
                        {

                        ***FileInputStream inputStream=new FileInputStream(uploadFilePath + saveFile);                                      

                        Workbook w = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputStream);

                        Sheet read_sheet = w.getSheet(0);***

                        int rows=read_sheet.getRows();


                        for (int j=1;j<rows;j++){
                                String[] fields=new String[4];

                            for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++)
                            {
                                Cell cell=read_sheet.getCell(i,j);
                                fields[i]=cell.getContents().trim();
                                if(fields[0] != null ){
                                    try{
                                        if (fields[i].indexOf(".") > 0) {
                                            if (i != 1) {
                                                fields[i] = fields[i];
                                            }else  {
                                                fields[i].substring(0, fields[i].indexOf("."));
                                            } 
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e1)
                                    {
                                        int k=i+1;
                                        errorVector.add("Invalid data at field "+k);
                                        System.out.println(" err1 :" + e1.toString());
                                        errorId = 1;
                                    }
                                }


                            }

                            if(!(fields[0] == null || (fields[0].trim().equals(""))))
                            {
                                rowVector.add(fields);
                            }
                            else{
                                break;
                            }                           
                        }
                        uploadObject.setErrorId(errorId);
                        uploadObject.setErrorVector(errorVector);
                        uploadObject.setRowVector(rowVector);

                        errorId = uploadObject.getErrorId();
                        rowVector = uploadObject.getRowVector();
                        errorVector = uploadObject.getErrorVector();

                        if (errorId == 0) {
                            int row = 0;
                            if (rowVector.size() > 0) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < rowVector.size(); i++) {
                                    IndexValueReportObject indexValueReportObj =
                                        new IndexValueReportObject();




                                    String[] fields =
                                        rowVector.elementAt(i);

                                    System.out.println("abc>>>>>"+fields[0]);
                                    System.out.println("abc>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+fields[1]);
                                    System.out.println("abc>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+fields[2]);
                                    System.out.println("abc>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>"+fields[3]);

                                    try{
                                    indexValueReportObj                                         
                                        .setDate(
                                        Timestamp.valueOf(fields[0]));
                                    }catch (Exception e1)
                                    {
                                        row = i + 1;
                                        vector.add("Invalid Date at row " + (row+1));
                                    }
                                    try{
                                    indexValueReportObj                                         
                                        .setPlatts(
                                        new BigDecimal(fields[1]));
                                    }catch (Exception e1)
                                    {
                                        row = i + 1;
                                        vector.add("Invalid Platts Value at row " + (row+1));
                                    }
                                    try{
                                    indexValueReportObj                                         
                                        .setArgus(
                                                new BigDecimal(fields[2]));
                                    }catch (Exception e1)
                                    {
                                        row = i + 1;
                                        vector.add("Invalid Argus Value at row " + (row+1));
                                    }
                                    try{
                                    indexValueReportObj                                         
                                        .setTsi(
                                                new BigDecimal(fields[3]));
                                    }catch (Exception e1)
                                    {
                                        row = i + 1;
                                        vector.add("Invalid TSI value at row " + (row+1));
                                    }


                                    indexObjectVector.add(
                                            indexValueReportObj);
                                }
                            } else {
                                vector.add(
                                    "No Bidder is created in the excel file ");
                            }
                        } else {

                            for (int k = 0; k < errorVector.size(); k++) {
                                String errorDescription =
                                    (String) errorVector.get(k);

                                vector.add(errorDescription);
                            }

                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e1) {

                        errorId = uploadObject.getErrorId();
                        rowVector = uploadObject.getRowVector();
                        errorVector = uploadObject.getErrorVector();


                        for (int k = 0; k < errorVector.size(); k++) {
                            String errorDescription =
                                (String) errorVector.get(k);

                            vector.add(errorDescription);
                        }
                    }
                    String filePathAndName=uploadFilePath + saveFile;

                    System.out.println("indexObjectVector"+indexObjectVector);
                    request.setAttribute(
                        IConstant.INDEX_OBJECT_VECTOR,
                        indexObjectVector);
                    request.getSession().setAttribute(
                        IConstant.FILE_NAME,
                        filePathAndName);
                    request.setAttribute(IConstant.UPLOAD_MESSAGE, "uploaded");

                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    vector.add("File name or sheet name error ");
                }

            } else {
                vector.add("File Type mismatch ");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            vector.add("No excel has been selected ");
        }
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {

            request.setAttribute(IConstant.ERROR_VECTOR, errors);
            forward = mapping.findForward("failureUpload");
        } else {
            forward = mapping.findForward("success");
        }

            return forward;



    }



}
```

In Workbook portion I want to read the excel file from local directory. When I run this code in debug mode, the control is going into exception block and forward it in my success page. So can some one please help me with this? I put sysout in that portion but nothing shows. I am using JXl for excel read and write. My confusion is in 3 star portion.

Comment: A wall of code like this is not a good question. Try to create a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: I have already specify the position that i confused.its start with  ***

Comment: @NirmalyaRoykarmakar The point is that making people dig through ~400 lines of a *single method* is not a great way to get people to help. There are several things wrong with this. Obviously the path you're supplying is incorrect. Why is it incorrect? No clue, not going to wade through a massive ~400 lines to try to figure it out. What I will do, though, is fix this horrible mess of Java code.

Comment: After formatting consistently, it's even worse than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but a partial refactoring.

This is an abomination of an action. There is zero way this should have ever passed any code review:

- Actions and business logic should be completely separate.
- Methods should be responsible for a single responsibility. This method:

  - Checks content type (arguably reasonable since that's web-related)
  - Manually parses the form (inexcusable; use a library)
  - Processes an Excel file (inexcusable; extract) which in turn:

    - Validates against business logic
    - Converts Excel values to BO values

The amount of un-equivalent work the action does defies explanation. This makes it essentially impossible to reason about, debug, fix, or anything. The below is a *very* rough start of refactoring, but you have another day or two of work to properly isolate levels of functionality and error handling (which is wrong, by the way, because you never check `vector`, possibly the worst-named variable in history, for errors, it's just thrown away?!?!?!)

```
public class IndexValueAction extends EPSBaseAction {
  public IndexValueAction() {
    super();
  }

  boolean isValidContentType(contentType) {
    return (contentType != null) && (contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)
  }

  String readContent(request) throws Exception {
    DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(request.getInputStream());

    int             formDataLength = request.getContentLength();
    byte            dataBytes[]    = new byte[formDataLength];
    int             totalBytesRead = 0;

    while (totalBytesRead < formDataLength) {
      totalBytesRead += in.read(dataBytes, totalBytesRead, formDataLength);
    }

    return new String(dataBytes);
  }

  void scanFile(realPath, outFilePath, errors) throws Exception {
    if (!FileScanner.loadProperty(realPath)) {
      return false;
    }

    if (!FileScanner.cleanFile(outFilePath)) {
      FileScaner.cleanFile(outFilePath);
      errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, new ActionError("errors.dynamic", "<li>Virus found!!"));
      return;
    }

    if (!FileScanner.checkFileSign(outFilePath)) {
      FileScaner.cleanFile(filepath);
      errors.add(ActionErrors.GLOBAL_ERROR, new ActionError("errors.dynamic", "<li>File type not supported!!"));
    }
  }

  IndexValueReportObject loadIndexValueReportObject(String[] fields, int i, Vector<String> vector) {
    IndexValueReportObject indexValueReportObj = new IndexValueReportObject();

    try {
      indexValueReportObj.setDate(Timestamp.valueOf(fields[0]));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      vector.add("Invalid Date at row " + (i + 2));
    }

    try {
      indexValueReportObj.setPlatts(new BigDecimal(fields[1]));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      vector.add("Invalid Platts Value at row " + (i + 2));
    }

    try {
      indexValueReportObj.setArgus(new BigDecimal(fields[2]));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      vector.add("Invalid Argus Value at row " + (i + 2));
    }

    try {
      indexValueReportObj.setTsi(new BigDecimal(fields[3]));
    } catch (Exception e) {
      vector.add("Invalid TSI value at row " + (i + 2));
    }

    return indexValueReportObj;
  }

  @Override
  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
    Vector<String> vector = new Vector<String>();

    if (!isValidContentType(request.getContentType())) {
      vector.add("File Type mismatch");
      return mapping.findForward("failureUpload");
    }

    String file;
    try {
      file = readContent(request);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      vector.add("No excel has been selected");
      return mapping.findForward("failureUpload");
    }

    ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
    try {
      String saveFile = file.substring(file.indexOf("filename=\"") + 10);
             saveFile = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf("\n"));
             saveFile = saveFile.substring(saveFile.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1,  saveFile.indexOf("\""));

      int    lastIndex = contentType.lastIndexOf("=");
      String boundary  = contentType.substring(lastIndex + 1, contentType.length());

      int pos = file.indexOf("filename=\"");
          pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
          pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;
          pos = file.indexOf("\n", pos) + 1;

      int boundaryLocation = file.indexOf(boundary, pos) - 4;
      int startPos         = ((file.substring(0, pos)).getBytes()).length;
      int endPos           = file.substring(0, boundaryLocation).getBytes().length;

      Vector<IndexValueReportObject> indexObjectVector = new Vector<IndexValueReportObject>();

      SimpleDateFormat df         = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy hh-mm-ss");
      String           fileSuffix = "-" + df.format(new Date()) + ".xls";
                        saveFile   = saveFile.substring(0, saveFile.indexOf(".")) + fileSuffix;

      ServletContext sc1        = request.getSession().getServletContext();
      Properties     properties = new Properties();
      String         realPath1  = sc1.getRealPath("serverPath.properties");

      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(realPath1);
      properties.load(fis);
      String uploadFilePath = properties.getProperty("fileUpload.path");
      FileOutputStream fileOut =    new FileOutputStream(uploadFilePath + saveFile);
      System.out.println(uploadFilePath);
      if (endPos > dataBytes.length) {
        endPos = dataBytes.length;
      }

      fileOut.write(dataBytes, startPos, (endPos - startPos));
      fileOut.flush();
      fileOut.close();

      Vector<String []> rowVector = new Vector<String[]>();
      Vector<Object> errorVector  = new Vector<Object>();
      UploadObject   uploadObject = new UploadObject();
      int            errorId      = 0;

      try {
        ServletContext sc          = getServlet().getServletContext();
        String         realPath    = sc.getRealPath("virusCheck.properties");
        File           outFile     = new File(uploadFilePath  + saveFile);
        String         outFilePath = outFile.getAbsolutePath();

        scanFile(realPath, outFilePath, errors);
        if (errors.isEmpty()) {
          FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(uploadFilePath + saveFile);
          Workbook        w           = Workbook.getWorkbook(inputStream);
          Sheet           read_sheet  = w.getSheet(0);***
          int             rows        = read_sheet.getRows();

          for (int j = 1; j < rows; j++) {
            String[] fields = new String[4];
            for(int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
              Cell cell = read_sheet.getCell(i, j);
              fields[i] = cell.getContents().trim();
              if (fields[0] != null) {
                try {
                  if (fields[i].indexOf(".") > 0) {
                    if (i != 1) {
                      fields[i] = fields[i];
                    } else {
                      fields[i].substring(0, fields[i].indexOf("."));
                    }
                  }
                } catch(Exception e1) {
                  int k = i+1;
                  errorVector.add("Invalid data at field " + k);
                  errorId = 1;
                }
              }
            }

            if (!(fields[0] == null || (fields[0].trim().equals("")))) {
              rowVector.add(fields);
            } else {
              break;
            }
          }

          uploadObject.setErrorId(errorId);
          uploadObject.setErrorVector(errorVector);
          uploadObject.setRowVector(rowVector);

          if (errorId == 0) {
            if (rowVector.size() > 0) {
              for (int i = 0; i < rowVector.size(); i++) {
                String[] fields = rowVector.elementAt(i);
                indexObjectVector.add(loadIndexValueReportObject(loadIndexValueReportObject(fields, i, vector)));
              }
            } else {
              vector.add("No Bidder is created in the excel file ");
            }
          } else {
            for (int k = 0; k < errorVector.size(); k++) {
              String errorDescription = (String) errorVector.get(k);
              vector.add(errorDescription);
            }
          }
        }
      } catch (Exception e1) {
        errorId     = uploadObject.getErrorId();
        rowVector   = uploadObject.getRowVector();
        errorVector = uploadObject.getErrorVector();

        for (int k = 0; k < errorVector.size(); k++) {
          String errorDescription = (String) errorVector.get(k);
          vector.add(errorDescription);
        }
      }

      request.setAttribute(IConstant.UPLOAD_MESSAGE, "uploaded");
      request.setAttribute(IConstant.INDEX_OBJECT_VECTOR, indexObjectVector);
      request.getSession().setAttribute(IConstant.FILE_NAME, uploadFilePath + saveFile);
    } catch (Exception e1) {
      vector.add("File name or sheet name error ");
    }

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      request.setAttribute(IConstant.ERROR_VECTOR, errors);
      return mapping.findForward("failureUpload");
    }

    return mapping.findForward("success");
  }
}
```